# Angular 2 Navigate inside of the same component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In "ProfileComponent" which displays the current profile, there is a list of other profiles so when i try to navigate to the other profile by...

```
this.router.navigate(['/profile/' + profileID]);
```

It changes params in url from `http://localhost:4200/profile/fsfterthjkj5`

to `http://localhost:4200/profile/hj45k35v`

but the component keeps showing the same profile. 
I can re-render the component by simply assigning the new profile to the old one and angular updates all data on the page BUT... how do i do that in way i can go back to the old profile by clicking "back" button in browser.

I tried reload the page after params are changed - that way angular also renders the profile i need but still i can't go back, params just change in url and no effect on the page, and it makes no sense request the same data after reloading while there were already loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to navigate to the same component with different parameters you need to subscribe to the route parameter's Observable.

The import:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

The constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

The OnInit lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            const id = +params['id'];
            this.getMovie(id);
        }
    );
}
```

Every time the route parameters change without changing the component, the code within the subscribe method will execute.

In this example, I pull the id from the parameters and use it to get the movie with the defined id.

Something like this should work for your scenario.

Comment: BTW. I learned angular via you tutorial in pluralsight..))) So thanks a lot on that as well !!) You are Great!

Comment: Thank you so much! (And I have an Angular Routing course as well if you are interested in more routing details such as this: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing )

Comment: Yes Ma'am! This project is scaling way faster than i expected. So i'll definitely have a look on this course. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OK solved i guess...
just implemented this `[href]="testFunc(profile.userId)"`

```
testFunc(id){ return '/profile/' + id;}
```

Comment: This may not be the best answer. It basically "skips" the routing. This may cause other problems for you. When you want to navigate to the same component with different parameters you need to subscribe to the route parameter's Observable.